# R basic addition with integer and decimal

Tags: r, addition

i am new to R , i had a basic addition doubt
suppose

```
a <- 2.656779e-08
b <- 1
s < a+b
1
```

i like to know why im not getting the exact value. Im a total beginner to R

Thanks in advance

Comment: The value is being stored correctly, this just has to do with how it is printed. Try running `options(digits=15); a+b` and note the result.

Comment: although if `a` is < about 2e-16, `a+1` will equal 1 exactly ...

Comment: ja , it works. Thanks for the tip! .

Comment: Just one additional note - you're adding two decimals there. Or numeric as it's called in R. You can see it by trying either `str(b)` or `class(b)`. If you want to make an integer, then you have to add "L" to the end of it. `b <- 1L` would result in b being an integer.

Comment: @nrussell also i had a doubt regarding extracting data from database. the problem is, between each row bind of information, i am getting NA value? any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's sounds like an entirely separate issue. You should ask this in a new question.

Comment: @nrussell, post as answer ...

Comment: can some submit the solution @nrussell as answer else i will be blocked from asking further questions ..please!

Comment: Apologies - I'm almost finished with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the above comments:

---

[myself]:

Adding a very small floating point decimal amount to a (relatively) much larger number only *appears* to return an incorrect value:

```
## default
R>  options()["digits"]
# $digits
# [1] 7
##
a <- 2.656779e-08
b <- 1
##
R>  a+b
# [1] 1
##
```

This really just has to do with the default print / display settings. Internally, however, `a+b` is accurately represented (i.e. `a+b != b == 1.0`) There are probably a dozen or so ways to demonstrate this; here are a few that quickly come to mind:

```
R>  all.equal(a+b,1)
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 2.656779e-08"
##
R>  (a+b)-1
# [1] 2.656779e-08
## 
R>  all.equal(a,(a+b)-1)
# [1] TRUE 
## 
options(digits=15) 
R>  a+b
# [1] 1.00000002656779
```

---

[@Ben Bolker]:

My first statement above comes with an important caveat - if you test `all.equal(1, 1 + x)` for increasingly small values of `x`, you will inevitably cross a threshold where this expression returns `TRUE`. As Ben pointed out, this threshold occurs at about `2e-16`. Additionally, I believe this is echoed by the following passage taken from the help file `?.Machine`:

> **double.eps**
>
> the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1. It
>   equals double.base ^ ulp.digits if either double.base is 2 or
>   double.rounding is 0; otherwise, it is (double.base ^
>   double.ulp.digits) / 2. Normally 2.220446e-16.

---

[@LauriK]:

Despite the fact that a simple `1` appears to be an `integer`, R will treat this as a `numeric` by default unless you specify otherwise, e.g. by using `as.integer`, `1L`, etc... You can verify that the object `b` from your example is not an `integer` class object by using `class(b)`, `str(b)`, or `is.integer(b)`, for example.